# Postgres how to find rows where in jsonb type column contains key with array which contain some value with or condition

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, where-clause, jsonb

I use PostgreSQL 11.8 and faced task, where I need save many sizes for product and need search by sizes too. Before  have structure without nested, only one level, without multiply `SIZE` key

```
{"SIZE": "98/104", "COLOUR": "Korall", "GENDER": "female", "CURRENCY": "SEK", "AGE_GROUP": "Kids", "ALTERNATIVE_IMAGE": "https://i1.adis.ws/i/Lindex/8016913_8414_PS_MF?w=300&h=300"}
```

and search I did like that

```
         WHERE ((products_alias.extras @> '{"SIZE":"One Size"}' 
                     OR products_alias.extras @> '{"SIZE":"146/152"}')                       
                     AND (products_alias.extras @> '{"COLOUR":"Flerfärgat"}' 
                     OR products_alias.extras @> '{"COLOUR":"Grå"}'
                     ))
```

But now I need provide opportunity save multiply `SIZE` and refactor search for that. Example if data will be look like that

```
{"SIZE": ["38", "90", "12", "4"], "COLOUR": "Svart", "GENDER": "female", "CURRENCY": "SEK", "AGE_GROUP": "Adult", "ALTERNATIVE_IMAGE": "https://i1.adis.ws/i/Lindex/7962770_80_PS_MF?w=300&h=300"}
```

how build search query for search by `SIZE` key with `OR` condition. Like search all where `SIZE` can contain value `38` or value `4` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the searched values in an array of texts, and use the `?|` operator:

```
where extras -> 'SIZE' ?| array['38', '4']
```

This checks whether the nested JSONB array on the left side of the operator contains any of the values in the text array on the right side.

If you want the JSONB array to contain *all* the target values, then use `?&` instead of `?|`.

Answer (score 2):

The [`@>` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) works on nested structures as well. To check whether the array contains 38 or 4, you can use

```
products_alias.extras @> '{"SIZE":["4"]}' OR products_alias.extras @> '{"SIZE":["38"]}'
```

To check whether the array contains both, you could use

```
products_alias.extras @> '{"SIZE":["4","38"]}'
```